# float left - extra space in the end of row

Tags: css, css-float

I have `div` with input controls in the left and button in the right. The input control count may vary based on the requirement.
The problem is that, when the i/p control is more that 4 (in 1600X900 resolution) the controls are not aligned properly i.e. the the controls are aligned in two lines are there is some extra space at the end of the row.

**HTML**

```
<div id ="Container">
    <div style="float: left;display: inline;max-width: 90%;">
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="One" >One:</label>
            <input id = "One" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Two">Two:</label>
            <input id = "Two" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Three">Three:</label>
            <input id = "Three" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Four">Four:</label>
            <input id = "Four" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Five" >Five:</label>
            <input id = "Five" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Six">Six:</label>
            <input id = "Six" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Seven" >Seven:</label>
            <input id = "Seven" type ="text" />
        </div>
        <div class =" divStyle">
            <label for ="Eight">Eight:</label>
            <input id = "Eight" type ="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
     <div style="float: left;display: inline;position: relative;" >
         <button type ="button">Hello World</button>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    label
    {
        float:left;
        min-width: 150px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    input
    {
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    .divStyle
    {
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        min-height:30px;            
    }
```

**Image**

[image]

[image: Image 2]

But if the I/P controls are <=4 the button is aligned properly

[image]

It may be fixed with the following css. but it is not working in all resolutions

```
    div:nth-child(4n+1)
    {
        clear:left;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UH4VH/4/

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: A recomendation, [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) makes your life easy to this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are mixing pixel and percent values.

You have set `min-width:150px` for `label` and `90%` for outer div.

Either set `max-width` of `label` in percent OR set `max-width` of outer div in percent.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UH4VH/8/)

[Output here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UH4VH/8/embedded/result/)

Dont use inline styles. It is a very bad practice.